# Images does not shown on Mvx.MvxImageView (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to learn mvvmcross and I am a newbie now. I started to watch N + 1 days of MvvmCross video series and I am stuck at N = 2 Kittens and Lists. I add DownloadCashPlugin and FilePlugin to the project and create Mvx.MvxImageView as shown on the video but when I start my app(both simulator and android device), everything is same but images does not shown or not downloaded. I open permission from android manifest and I have an internet connection on my android device. I am pretty sure I follow videos carefully and dont miss any part.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 Communtiy Edition and MvvmCross is last updated version. I will be glad if anyone can help me on this problem. Thank you.

Item_Kitten.axml ;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxImageView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ImageUrl" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text Price" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show some code from the ViewModel, specifically the part setting the ImageUrl property? Please check the Visual Studio "Output" window for any hints as to what may be wrong.

Comment: Could you link to the tutorial? Maybe the Image is not available anymore.